# I need an example for an amp form with recaptcha

Tags: recaptcha, amp-html

I could not find enough examples to an amp form with recaptcha.

What should I add to the amp form to make the recaptcha work?
could you please tell me what I am missing?

1. I put this code in the head:

   ```
   script async custom-element="amp-recaptcha-input" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-recaptcha-input-0.1.js"
   ```
2. I put the submit button and changed the sitekey to my website key:

   ```
   input name="submit-button" type="submit" value="Submit"

   amp-recaptcha-input layout="nodisplay" name="recaptcha_example" data- 
   sitekey="6LebBGoUAAAAAHbj1oeZMBU_rze_CutlbyzpH8VE" data- 
   action="recaptcha_example"
   ```

It does not work,what else am I missing?

Should I change the form action= to form action-xhr= ?

Do I need to add the recaptcha secret key somewhere?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, but an example for that component is available here: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/examples/recaptcha.amp.html